# C++/CLI: Interpreting "VOID" as "void"

Tags: c++-cli

I am doing something pretty ugly but nevertheless there seems to be something what appears to be a bug ..

I have an `enum` called `BasicTypeID` which is written in **C#**:

```
public enum BasicTypeID
{
    //..
    FUNCTION,
    VOID,
    FLOAT,
    // ..
}
```

As I try to assign a value to an array element on position BasicTypeID::VOID like this:

```
typedef struct TypeInfo {
    char * name;
    unsigned char size;
    unsigned char sign;
    unsigned char real;
} TypeInfo;

static const TypeInfo TYPE_VOID = { "void", 0, 0, 0 };

static TypeInfo const **basic_type_info;

CDLLEXPORT void CLIParser_InitializeDebugInformation(char * source_folder_path, char * cdb_file_path) 
{
  // ..

  int enum_size = Enum::GetNames(BasicTypeID::typeid)->Length;

  *basic_type_info = new TypeInfo[enum_size];

  basic_type_info[(int)BasicTypeID::VOID] = &TYPE_VOID; // Compile error

  VOID *dummy1;
  FLOAT dummy2;

  // ..
}
```

I am receiving the errors:

```
error C2589: 'void' : illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

whereas it is working if I use e.g. `FUNCTION` as index:

```
basic_type_info[(int)BasicTypeID::FUNCTION] = &TYPE_VOID; // Compiles without errors
```

it is also working for `FLOAT`:

```
basic_type_info[(int)BasicTypeID::FLOAT] = &TYPE_VOID; // Compiles without errors
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: @T.C.: Yeah, portability, just in case Windows is ever ported to a platform where `VOID` should be defined differently ;-).

Comment: @rodrigo I think that this was from the time before `void` was uniformly supported by all C compilers. Then backwards compatibility made it impossible to take it out.

Comment: So where are FUNCTION and VOID defined in your code?

Comment: @T.C.: I think you should post that as an answer

Comment: Correction: It should be `#define VOID void`. Should have gotten my coffee first...

Comment: @T.C. Well that would make, but that would mean, that the parser completely ignores the fact, that this is a member of an `enum` and doesn't care about `BasicTypeID::` at all..

Comment: @StefanFalk `#define` is part of the preprocessor. It messes up your code well before the actual parsing takes place.

Comment: This is one reason (beyond the mere aeshthetic) to avoid `SHOUTY_CAPS` for anything except macros.

Comment: Well I agree but `static const` types are also candidates for uppercase naming imho.

Comment: The [.NET guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) may look arbitrary.  There were not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows headers have a `#define VOID void`, which messes up your C++/CLI code.

Why did they do this? Because back in the day when the Windows API was first defined, C compiler support for `void` wasn't uniform. Since the API has to work with these compilers, it supplied its own version in `VOID`, which is presumably expanded to `void` if your compiler supports it, or some other type if it doesn't. Then, they can't do anything about it because of backward compatibility.

Why not a typedef? Because apparently the Microsoft compilers at that time didn't consider `typedef void VOID;` to be legal C (they now do, I believe). And they had to retain the macro for backward compatibility, because while

```
#define VOID void
int c(VOID){ return 0; }
```

is legal,

```
typedef void VOID;
int c(VOID){ return 0; }
```

is not (in C89, anyway).

Pretty much all the other Windows API types are typedefs and not preprocessor macros, which is why `FLOAT` works for you but `VOID` doesn't.

Comment: Well I thought this might be it but for whatever reason this works if I replace `BasicTypeID::VOID` by `BasicTypeID::FLOAT`.. that is very strange .. see my edit

Comment: @StefanFalk `FLOAT` is a typedef, not a macro.

Comment: But it's still a little strange that the parser ignores the `BasicTypeID::` prefix ..

Comment: @StefanFalk A `#define` basically does a token-level search-and-replace before your code even got to the compiler's parser. What the parser sees is `BasicTypeID::void`, which is obviously illegal.

Comment: Well yes, I guess so. That would make sense. Thank you :)